# LINQ connecting Many - Many relationships

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, repeater

I am using c#.net and LINQ

Within my LINQ model I have three database tables:

[LINQ MODEL http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/9827/linqmodel.jpg](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/9827/linqmodel.jpg)

The code below is how I access the data:

```
    public IQueryable<tblAvailability> GetAvailabilitiesBySet(int id)
    {
        return (from a in dc.tblAvailabilities
                where a.asID == id
                select a).DefaultIfEmpty();
    }
```

I display the data to screen (via a repeater). However I cannot seem to access the 'appTypeName' located within tblAppointmentType. I thought I could access it like this:

```
<%#Eval("tblAvailabilities.tblAvailabilityAppointmentType.tblAppointmentType.appTypeName")%>
```

But it will not let me access tblAppointmentType. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Clare

Comment: Please provide the exact error message. From your data model and the code, I do not see how it could possibly be what you imply it to be; I'd rather expect it to complain about `tblAvailabilities`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added another repeater inside the first repeater with accessed the correct database table.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ2Sql doesn't handle Many-2-Many well without a little hand-holding...

remove the link between tblAvailabiltyAppointmentType and tblAppoitmentType.  Make a new link FROM tblAvailabiltyAppointmentType TO tblAppoitmentType.  click on that new link to get to the properties.  change the Cardinality to OneToOne (since you can't pick ManyToOne), open up the Cild Property section, and change the name to singular.

now, when you perform the query you have in the question, the tblAvailability object will have a collection tblAvailabilityAppointmentTypes, and each tblAvailabilityAppointmentType object in that collection will have a property object tblAppointmentType, which has the appTypeName field you're looking for.

```
var appTypes = GetAvailabilitiesBySet(99).tblAvailabilityAppointmentTypes.
    Select(a=>a.appTypeName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not joined any of the other tables, hence the results are only bringing back the tblAvailabilities rows.

```
var query = (from avail in dc.tblAvailabilitities
        join aaTyp in dc.tblAvailabilityAppointmentType
             on avail.availabilityID == aaType.availabilityID
        join appType in dc.tblAppointmentType
             on aaType.appTypeID == appType.appTypeID
        select new { TypeName = appType.appTypeName });
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current schema, you would possibly have multiple records for tblAvailabilityAppointmentType per record in tblAvailabilities.  That means you need to get a specific entry before trying to tie into tblAppointmentType.  Also, you are not joining in the other tables to retrieve the rows (if you want to do it that way).

As an aside, is many to many really what you want here?  Your usage (as well as the concepts I infer from your naming) makes it seem like you want a one to many relationship. Perhaps many tblAvailabiliy records, each referencing one tblAppointmentType?

If you do want many to many, you may be well served extending the tblAvailabilities class with a GetAppointmentTypes() method.  Here's [a decent article on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/LINQ_many2many.aspx?fid=337342&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2624941&fr=1).

Othewise,  make sure you join in the other tables and reference the right row in tblAppointmentType